# How to download a built package from Visual Studio Xamarin to Android Device?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Yes, I did Google this.  And googled it.  And googled it.  And read two books on it.  No answers found, and this should be in section one of every tutorial out there:

I've got my nice Xamarin forms app built and compiled in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and now I want install it on my Android tablet and telephone.  There's nothing out there telling me how to do this.  Build a package?  Pray for a miracle?  What do I do?  I've looked at all the compiled output of a Release build in Visual Studio and there's nothing in there that looks like it can be moved to an Android device.

For the record, my Android devices have been placed in USB debug mode, are connecting easily to my Windows development machine, and I can see the 'droids as if they're external drives, so getting a package of some sort over to them should be a piece of cake.

I MUST be missing something obvious.  Please, enlighten me?

Comment: Create an `.apk` and publish (assuming not via Play Store), thus  `https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/visual-studio-xa-4.2.6-to-6.1/` & `https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_6_-_publishing_independently/` (SO does not like commas in Urls, so copy/paste...)

Comment: There were indeed some Visual Studio instructions buried there!  They just had them hidden underneath the Xamarin IDE instructions.  I'm going to give it another run as soon as my dev machine finishes rebuilding (VS 2015 Community on Windows 8 isn't very stable, blew me out of the water :()  Thanks for the links.